# simplexml_load_file() и кириллический дмоен

Tags: php, кириллица, simplexml

Есть код для обновления информации о товарах из другого магазина через файл Яндекс.Маркета. В начале я подгружаю файл с помощью simplexml_load_file(). Сайт одного из новых клиентов размещается на кириллическом домене (итоговая ссылка на файл по типу 'мойсайт.рф/pricelist.xml'), в итоге ничего не работает. Пытался элементарно перевести домен в punycode — не работает.

Мастера, подскажите, как мне быть? Всякие дополнительные библиотеки ставить не могу, т.к. хостинг виртуальный. Заранее всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Простейшая проверка говорит что всё должно работать:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('https://xn----7sbb5aamccpiegbel3bh1td.xn--p1ai/sitemap.xml');

foreach ($xml->url as $line) {
    echo "{$line->loc}\n";
}
```

Проверьте, нет ли ошибки DNS:

```
var_dump(gethostbyname('xn----7sbb5aamccpiegbel3bh1td.xn--p1ai'));
```

Если ошибки DNS нет (команда выше возвращает IP адрес), и вы можете загрузить файл локально из браузера, то обращайтесь в поддержку хостинга.

В вашем конкретном случае похоже на сервере блокируются запросы без заголовка User-Agent. Это легко исправить так:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('http://xn--80aaanvlco2b3a.xn--p1ai/pricelist.xml', false, stream_context_create([
  'http' => [
    'header' => 'User-Agent: PHP'
  ]
]));

$xml = simplexml_load_string($file);

var_dump($xml->shop->name);
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но происходит что-то странное.
Проверка с газетой Навального работает, var_dump тоже возвращает, а именно мой конкретный файл не грузит.
Возвращает false:  

`$file = 'http://xn--80aaanvlco2b3a.xn--p1ai/pricelist.xml';
$yml_catalog = simplexml_load_file($file);`

Comment: Скрытая реклама газеты Навального?

Comment: @Эшли обновил ответ